# Output to new data set

Tags: sas

Suppose that I have a model and I want to output the studentized residuals, leverages, Cook's Distance and the DFFITS statistics from my regression model to a new data set. How would I do this?

Comment: You can probably get a more specific answer if you post your code with some example data - I answered in the general form below, assuming you know what proc to use.

Answer (score 2):

Answering as a general question of how do I get certain pieces of output from a proc to a dataset, you will want to look at ODS TRACE.

```
ods trace on;
proc reg <stuff>;
<stuff>;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Now, look at the log, and see what different output options you have.  All of the different things that go to the screen will be here, plus additional tables sometimes that don't go to any output window by default.  Find the `name` for the tables you want data from, and then direct them to an `ods output` statement.

```
ods output <name>=<datasetname>;
proc reg <stuff>;
<stuff>;
run;
ods output close;
```

You can specify multiple names and multiple output datasets, assuming you want more than one thing.